# ndarray rust, change values of a slice

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

In python's numpy given an array

```
a = np.zeros((10,10,2))
```

I could modify values of the array corresponding to a slice 4:6,: as such:

```
a[4:6,:] = [0,255]
```

In rust: given a ndarray from the ndarray package, i can slice

```
let mut img = Array3::<u8>::zeros((10,10,2));
let slice = img.slice_mut(s![4..6,..,..]);
```

But what is the idiomatic way of changing the values of that slice, by broadcasting the subarray corresponding to the last axis i.e. [0,255]?

Answer (score 0):

through other means i found answer and im posting it here. One needs to combine slice_mut with method .assign(&stuff to broadcast)

```
 let mut img = Array3::<u8>::zeros((10,10,2));
 let arr = Array::ones(2);
 img.slice_mut(s![4..6usize,..,..]).assign(&arr);
```