# Assign values from a slice of a rust ndarray to an equivalent slice of another ndarray

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

In Python, say I have two 4D NumPy arrays (the exact number number of dimensions doesn't matter too much other than it being multi-dimensional):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((4, 5, 6, 7))
b = np.zeros((4, 5, 6, 7))
```

If I want to assign a certain slice from `b` into `a`, I could do, e.g.,:

```py
a[1:3, 0:2, 1::2, :] = b[1:3, 0:2, 1::2, :]
```

If I have two 4D rust [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/index.html)'s, e.g.,

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*

fn main() {
  let mut a = Array4::<f64>::ones((4, 5, 6, 7));
  let b = Array4::<f64>::zeros((4, 5, 6, 7));
}
```

how would I go about doing an equivalent assignment of a slice of `b` into `a`?

This is rather similar, but (I think) not quite the same as:

- [ndarray rust, change values of a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74753638/ndarray-rust-change-values-of-a-slice)
- [Is there a Rust ndarray equivalent for numpy arithmetic on a slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400966/is-there-a-rust-ndarray-equivalent-for-numpy-arithmetic-on-a-slice)

and there is information in [this Github thread](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/issues/419).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have found to do this is using the [`slice_mut`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.slice_mut) method, the [`assign`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.assign) method and the [`s!`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/macro.s.html) slice macro. For an exact match of the case above, we could do:

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut a = Array4::<f64>::ones((4, 5, 6, 7));
    let b = Array4::<f64>::zeros((4, 5, 6, 7));

    // assign a slice of b into an equivalent slice of a
    a.slice_mut(s![1..3, 0..2, 1..;2, ..]).assign(
        &b.slice(s![1..3, 0..2, 1..;2, ..])
    );
}
```